# Jquery Scrolling Carousel is not working in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, carousel

I am stuck in a problem...

Jq Scrollingcarousel Reference : http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/

This is the process i am doing...
http://jsfiddle.net/BnwLh/1/

The problem is that in my website its running smooth except in IE7...
It become still in ie7..

In above link of jsfiddle, currently is not working..
Can anyone fix it???

---

In this carousel, i am trying to add more functionality to it so i added two buttons left and right...
If you hover to Left, it should move left and If you hover to Right, it should move right...

I am trying with this code:

```
$("a.prev-go").mouseover(function() {
$('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel();
});
$("a.next-go").mouseover(function() {
$('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xLhmS/1/

But its not working for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel( {
        scrollerAlignment : "horizontal",
        autoScroll : true,
        autoScrollSpeed : 10000,
        scrollSpeed : "slow",
        scrollerOffset : 0,
        looped : true // for IE7 i put it to the end of the code and it worked well.
    }); 
}); // you forgot to add it at the end of the JQuery
```

[Working example Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/BnwLh/8/)